# Template for Telegram to send alert notification in Grafana Version 10

Tags: grafana

I need help. May I know in Grafana Version 10, is there any template for Telegram to send alert notification ?

I suggest to edit some part of it (remove url for example and put special name for each alert).

If there is no template, can you suggest how can I make some changes in Telegram alert notification.

Thanks.